# View's background is placed over the elements

Tags: android, view, background, android-relativelayout

Good Afternoon! I want to use an image as background in my view, the problem is that when I use an image (With a color works perfectly) the background is placed over the elements, so it's not possible to see nothing.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Greet"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_panel" >

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/logo_panel"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Do you know what's the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: the background of the `RelativeLayout` should be behind the `ImageView`? Or what is your desired configuration?

Comment: Yes, I want the ImageView over the background, not in the bottom

Comment: From the layout I can't see any reason why that should not work, can you please post a screenshot of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add the image as background to your RelativeLayout? So you don't need the ImageView and nothing overlaps.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Greet"
    android:background="@drawable/logo_panel" >

</RelativeLayout>
```